# How to assign the value of listbox after reloading

Tags: javascript

Im new to javascript and trying to get the value of listbox,then the page should reload, After that i want to assign that same value to listbox..Please help me to solve this ??

Comment: Can you please update your working code

Comment: Read the docs ( mdn has good ones ) about localStorage or cookies and the dom

Comment: Try writing it and if sth doesnt work come back and show us your code